# How did Alex know who Alan Parrish was?

Tags: jumanji, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle

In ***Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle***, after Alex Vreeke meets the four other players, he takes them back to a house in the jungle where he had been living for the past 20 years.

Alex explains that the house was built by Alan Parrish, the last person to play Jumanji. He knows this because of a note scratched into the house:

> Alan Parrish was here

**How did Alex Vreeke know that Alan Parrish was a previous Jumanji player?**

In the original ***Jumanji***, Alan Parrish was trapped in the jungle for 26 years from 1969 to 1995. In ***Welcome to the Jungle***, Alex Vreeke was trapped a year later in 1996, so the two couldn't have met each other.

It makes sense for Alex to assume that Alan Parrish built the house, but the note doesn't say anything about the house being made by a previous player.

Comment: Well, the house was inside Jumanji's magical reality, so unless it was part of the game (in which case nobody built it) it would have to have been built by a previous player.  Perhaps Alex came to the conclusion that it wasn't part of the game [because it had no relationship to the plot?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheLawOfConservationOfDetail) (Warning: TV Tropes.)

Comment: I would assume that there were some clues left, that we don't see on screen. Alex lived there for 20 years so he had plenty of time to find out.

Comment: It should also be noted that Alex mentions this in 2017 and has had 20 years to become accustomed to Jumanji and many of its traps and citizens.